# Fluxx - What counts as a 'play'?

Tags: fluxx

When the current rules in play are along the lines of 'Play 4', does that include any cards you have already played as the result of other actions / playing your Keepers, or do they have to be fresh cards from your hand?

If I have 2 action cards and 2 keepers in my hand and I have to play 4, do I have to also play the keepers in front of me? (I've interpreted the rules as such in this case)

(Zombie Fluxx in this case, but common to all variants of Fluxx I think?)

Answer (score 11):

One thing that may be worth clarifying (for new players) is that, if you've played one card already this turn and your second play is "Play 4", you don't play four more cards; you play two more cards.

Likewise, if you start your turn with "Play 4" in effect and your third play is "Play 2", you don't play any more cards; you have already played more than your currently allotted number of cards for the turn.

Playing cards as part of an action *doesn't* count towards your Play 4 limit, though.  For instance "Draw 3 and play 2 of them" counts as one of your four plays for the turn, not two or three.

Playing a Keeper or a Goal does very much count as playing a card.  Creepers don't, of course, but they're a well-documented special case.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, putting a keeper on the table in front of you counts as a play, but having a keeper on the table that you previously played is not a play.  (I'm not sure I understand your first paragraph, so I'm trying to answer what I think you're asking)

If the current rule is "play 4" you do have to play cards from your hand (including rules, actions, and keepers) until either:

1. You run out of cards
2. You play a rule card that changes the play # rule
3. You have played 4 cards

Comment: Cards already played this turn count toward the total.

Comment: @Neal: yes, cards played do count as cards played.

Answer (score 3):

Putting a keeper in front of you counts as playing it, so yes, in your example you would have to play all 4 cards.